Excel: Preserving formula-generated array inside of table after different sorting operations
I have a Page # column in a glossary table that I would like to auto-populate after a user inserts a starting number for that column:



Term
Page #




Antelope
103


Boar
104


Capybara
105



In this example, UserA inputs "103" next to the first term in the glossary ("Antelope"). If UserA decides to sort by Term ascending from Z-A, the output should be:



Term
Page #




Capybara
105


Boar
104


Antelope
103



Starting with the second cell in the Page # column (the cell just below "103"), I used the formula: =IF($D224="","",$D224+1). In this case, this formula is contained in cell D225, and is auto-filled down the Page # column, with each term referencing the previous one and incrementing the value by 1.
When a user sorts this, Excel returns a #VALUE! error.
I also tried to call out the sheet name to preserve the order, using the formula: =IF(Sheet1!$D224="","",$D224+1
This created some unusual results, and caused cells to reference themselves, so it won't work either.
Is there any way to use a formula that maintains the original array generated after the user inputs the first value in the Page # column, no matter how they choose to sort the table?
Thanks!

Not sure what the downvote is for, happy to clarify or reframe the question if needed.

Not sue either mate - so eliminated it - ta
(I didn't put downvote, fyi - just upvote) -- upon close inspection I have what I hope is interpreted purely as constructive feedback / suggestions (which shouldn't detract from the fact that you seem to have laid most of the content out in an organized way, with examples, and tables is which always appreciated - keeping in mind that I'm not an SME/Guru on this topic, you first port of call (I think/believe):
1- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask?utm_source=Iterable&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=gen-welcome-email&utm_content=aug18
PTO...

@Ecsizemore, I don't think it would work since the number assignment depends on the original position of the items (row number may change after sorting). Also, I'm not sure how insertions/deletions need to be handled. Static assignment with auto-fill may be safer.

Good to know, thanks for the help! I'll explore other options.

If you're willing to code some VBA, this would be pretty easy by detecting the entry of the first number with the Worksheet_Change event, then populating the column of numbers below it. Because you're adding values, not formulas, you can sort  or anything else.

I've been afraid to start learning VBA, but this seems like a good way to go. Thanks for the tip!

So is D224 the cell where you're trying to use this formula? So referencing itself (circular reference)

Good question, I should have included this information in the original post. Ideally, the user would input the first number of the array, and the formula I listed would start one cell below that (in this case, D225). From there, each cell references the previous one, adding one to the value. But the numbers are scrambled if the table is sorted.
